# How can I associate my models in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, model, nested

I am trying to develope an travel app. I have four model class whic are Place, Place_info , County and Category. County has a property that 'places'. This property's type is List. My Place object has a property that 'county'. This property's type is County.
When I want to create a Place object it goes to County class for creat Place's County object while it is creating a county object it goes to Place object to create County's Places list. İt is getting into a dead-end loop. I can't find any solution for this problem. Can you help me?

Here my models:

```
class Place {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String image;
  final List<County?> county;
  final List<PlaceInfo> placeInfos;
  final String firstInfo;
  final List<Category?> categories;

  Place({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    required this.county,
    required this.placeInfos,
    required this.firstInfo,
    required this.categories,
  });

  factory Place.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> place) => Place(
      id: place["id"],
      name: place["name"],
      image: place["image"],
      county: List.from(Repository().countiesJSON.map((countyJSON) {
        if (countyJSON.containsValue(place["countyId"])) {
          return County.fromMap(countyJSON);
        }
      }).toList()),

      placeInfos: List<PlaceInfo>.from(
        place["information"].map(
          (item) => PlaceInfo.fromMap(item),
        ),
      ),
      firstInfo: place["firstInfo"],
      categories: List.from(place["categoriesId"]
          .map(
            (categoyId) => Repository()
                .categoriesJSON
                .map((categoryJSON) {
                  if (categoryJSON.containsValue(categoyId)) {
                    return Category.fromMap(categoryJSON);
                  }
                })
                .iterator
                .current,
          )
          .toList()));
}

class PlaceInfo {
  final String infoTitle;
  final String info;

  PlaceInfo({
    required this.infoTitle,
    required this.info,
  });
  factory PlaceInfo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> placeInfo) => PlaceInfo(
        infoTitle: placeInfo["infoTile"],
        info: placeInfo["info"],
      );
}


class Category {
  String id;
  final String name;
  final String image;
  final List<Place?> places;

  Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    required this.places,
  });

  factory Category.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> category) => Category(
        id: category["id"],
        name: category["name"],
        image: category["image"],
        places: List.from(category["placesId"]
            .map(
              (placeId) => Repository()
                  .placesJSON
                  .map((placeJSON) {
                    if (placeJSON.containsValue(placeId)) {
                      return Place.fromMap(placeId);
                    }
                  })
                  .iterator
                  .current,
            )
            .toList()),
      );
}


class County {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String image;
  final List<Place?> places;

  County({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    required this.places,
  });

  factory County.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> county) => County(
        id: county["id"],
        name: county["name"],
        image: county["image"],
        places: List.from(county["placesId"]
            .map((placeId) => Repository().placesJSON.map((placeJSON) {
                  if (placeJSON.containsValue(placeId)) {
                    return Place.fromMap(placeJSON);
                  }
                }).toList())
            .toList()),
      );
}
```

Here my demo data:

```
var placesData = [
  {
    "id": "d",
    "name": "Dolmabahçe Sarayı",
    "image": "assets/images/dolmabahçe.jpg",
    "countyId": "b",
    "firstInfo": "Dolmabahçe Sarayı firstInfo",
    "information": [
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 1", "info": "bilgi 1 açıklama"},
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 2", "info": "bilgi 2 açıklama"},
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 3", "info": "bilgi 3 açıklama"},
    ],
    "categoriesId": [
      "m",
      "s",
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "a",
    "name": "Ayasofya",
    "image": "assets/images/ayasofya.webp",
    "countyId": "s",
    "firstInfo": "Ayasofya firstInfo",
    "information": [
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 1", "info": "bilgi 1 açıklama"},
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 2", "info": "bilgi 2 açıklama"},
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 3", "info": "bilgi 3 açıklama"},
    ],
    "categoriesId": [
      "c",
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "y",
    "name": "Yerebatan Sarnıcı",
    "image": "assets/images/yerebatan.webp",
    "countyId": "s",
    "firstInfo": "Yerebatan Sarnıcı firstInfo",
    "information": [
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 1", "info": "bilgi 1 açıklama"},
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 2", "info": "bilgi 2 açıklama"},
      {"infoTile": "bilgi 3", "info": "bilgi 3 açıklama"},
    ],
    "categoriesId": [
      "m",
    ],
  },
];

var categoriesData = [
  {
    "id": "m",
    "name": "Müze",
    "image": "assets/images/müze.webp",
    "placesId": [
      "d",
      "y",
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "r",
    "name": "Restorant",
    "image": "assets/images/restorant.webp",
    "placesId": [],
  },
  {
    "id": "e",
    "name": "Eğlence",
    "image": "assets/images/eğlence.webp",
    "placesId": [],
  },
  {
    "id": "s",
    "name": "Saray",
    "image": "assets/images/saray.webp",
    "placesId": [
      "d",
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "a",
    "name": "Alışveriş",
    "image": "assets/images/alışveriş.webp",
    "placesId": [],
  },
  {
    "id": "c",
    "name": "Cami",
    "image": "assets/images/cami.webp",
    "placesId": [
      "a",
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "d",
    "name": "Doğa",
    "image": "assets/images/doğa.webp",
    "placesId": [],
  },
];

var countiesData = [
  {
    "id": "b",
    "name": "Beşiktaş",
    "image": "assets/images/beşiktaş.jpg",
    "placesId": [
      "d",
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": "s",
    "name": "Sultanahmet",
    "image": "assets/images/Sultanahmet.jpg",
    "placesId": [
      "a",
      "y",
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: What does the actual data look like?

Comment: Now I created a demo data. I am using it for test but  then I will use Firebase. I added my demo data to my question